# Can't connect as root user with Samba

Tags: samba, smb

I can't connect as root user to my Samba share. However I think there is nothing wrong with my config file. But I noticed that I'm also unable to delete the root user from Samba. With other users no problems at all.

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
# Basic Samba configuration
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
security = user
printcap name = /dev/null
load printers = no
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=524288 SO_SNDBUF=524288
server string = Samba Server %v
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
wide links = yes
follow symlinks = yes
unix extensions = no
acl allow execute always = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
max log size = 1000

# Special configuration for Apple's Time Machine
fruit:model = MacPro
fruit:advertise_fullsync = true
fruit:aapl = yes

## Definde your shares here

[root]
comment = root
path=/
browseable=YES
writeable=YES
valid users= root
only guest=no
create mask=0777
directory mask=07777
public=no
force user = root
force group = root
```

root is in the passwd file...

When I try to remove root user :

```
sudo smbpasswd -x root
Failed to delete entry for user root.
```

I think there must be something wrong with the samba userdatabase??

Answer (score 0):

Ok ... I think I found out what's going on here. It looks like samba executables are on two locations :

```
maarten@UBUNTU:/usr/local/samba/bin$ whereis smbpasswd
smbpasswd: /usr/bin/smbpasswd /usr/local/samba/bin/smbpasswd
```

I think the installation got messed up. I upgraded to the newest Samba version manually. But it looks like the smbpasswd command is still pointing to the old version.